# SOAPUI Groovy UI Select a Random Value from Loaded List

Tags: random, groovy, soapui

I am using SOAPUI groovy script and I need a way to select a random value from a list. How can I handle this?

Example `def Cities= ["London", "NY", "Berlin"....etc]`

Answer (score 2):

Use Random to create a random number, then use that to access the array...

```
import java.util.Random
Random rand = new Random();
int max = 4  // Length of array
def randomNumber = rand.nextInt(max);

return Cities[randomNumber];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following solution. It generates a random int of length()

`${=org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(5)}`